Kendo Angular Scheduler custom view
I have a custom Kendo calendar for the scheduler using kendoSchedulerToolbarTemplate where I can select random multiple dates. After selecting the multiple dates, I need the scheduler to display for the selected dates. As of now we have views like kendo-scheduler-day-view, kendo-scheduler-week-view and kendo-scheduler-multi-day-view etc. The kendo-scheduler-multi-day-view accepts number of days, Suppose the no of days is 3, It shows scheduler views for continuous 3 dates.
I am trying to get scheduler view to show for the random multiple days selected from the Kendo calendar.
